# Node not sending scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, web, mean-stack

I'm trying to do this tutorial: http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-11/app/#/phones. When I place these files into MAMP, it works. However, when I try making a Node server, it doesn't send the js files. I checked using InspectElement. It only sends the index.html. Why is this happening?

```
//server.js

var express     = require('express');
var app         = express();
var port        = process.env.PORT || 8887;

app.configure(function()
{
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + './public'));
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
});

require('./app/router')(app);

app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening to port 8887');
exports = module.exports = app;


//./app/router.js

module.exports = function(app){
    app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html');
});
```

Comment: What if you try 
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `./public` to just `/public/` and make sure your scripts are in the public folder.